# Div with 100% width and height in table-cell changes size of table-cell when content is large

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a cell that is calculated by the html-table-algorithm (the cell in the lower right corner). This works exactly like I'm expecting it to work until I add content that is larger than the calculated cell (comment in the two lines if you want to test it).

Is there a way to work around this problem without using a fixed height and width (since the second row is also created with the html-table-algorithm and has only a fixed height to illustrate it in the example)?

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2Bu4/3/) for the JSFiddle.

The HMTL:

```
<table>
    <tr style="height: 40px">
        <td style="width: 200px;">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height: 40px">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="content">
                <!--
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 3000px; height: 40px;"></div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 40px; height: 3000px;"></div>
                -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body { 
    margin: 0; 
}

table{
    border: 1px solid red; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
}

table tr td{
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.content{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I want a scrollbar in the div without changing the size of the table-cell around it. At the moment the cell grows when the content is large (e.g 3000px). Comment out the two lines in the code: This destroys the layout. I want to comment out the two lines without changing the size of the table. Hope its clearer now, sorry :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update the content css class:

```
.content{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: max-width seems to work incorrectly in this scenario? The scrollbar is on the page, not the div here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/z2Bu4/17/). This is correct for you too, right? The scrollbar should be in the div. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Instead of max width in %, if you'll put max-width in pixels, than it will work.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, but a fixed width is not what I want to achieve. I want the div to be exactly as width as my table-cell. Is this even possible with pure css?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was pretty obvious. The table has to be fixed, not auto (which is specified [here](http://www.css4you.de/table-layout.html)).

My final code looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/patricebeutler/z2Bu4/85/) (JSFiddle).

And for visitors from the far future:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr style="height: 40px">
        <td style="width: 200px;">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height: 40px">
        <td style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px;">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px;">5</td>
        <td>
            <div class="content">
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 3000px; height: 40px;"></div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 40px; height: 3000px;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body { 
    margin: 0; 
}

table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

table tr td{
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid green;

    height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    overflow: auto;
}
```